# Options for getting/setting Windows window states for a browser window

Tags: windows, winapi, dom, cross-browser, activex

Our agency has a Java web application that uses a third party Java applet as a TIFF viewer. In this application javascript spawns a separate window (and yes, it must be a separate window). We are currently using an in-house ActiveX control so that the HTML window can have the window state, window size and position, and screen device presisted and restored via localStorage. Our agency is IE11 only so for now using it is not a problem. It's embedded in the page and operates on the "containing window".

This control was made many years ago in VB6. It appears that Visual Studio doesn't support the creation of ActiveX controls, and I don't personally have the knowledge or skill to create one another way.

Please **do not** suggest **the HTML DOM window and screen objects**! Most answers I've searched for just refer to these! They can't get the entire browser window size (viewport + chrome + toolbars + titlebar), nor does javascript have any idea about Windows-specific things like window state and screen device (it's always the OS primary screen). I understand the HTML DOM can't be tied to anything OS-specific in order for it to be implementable on multiple platforms.

Up until now this control has worked pretty well - you can, for example, maximize on a given screen and restore the window to the same screen. But I realize that ActiveX won't be supported forever and it's IE only...It seems to me, though, that the need for such functionality can't be totally uncommon. I'm guessing that some may suggest that the application UI should be changed so that this is less of a problem - but being able to put the viewer on a different monitor from the application, and having that window be restored exactly to it's last position is important to us. I do understand that if you reuse that window the user only has to position it once, but we'd rather not require this of the user.

**Question**: are there any alternatives to interacting with the win32 API other than COM/ActiveX ? Are there any other methods of **accurate** window persistence that can know about screens other than the OS primary, and maximized/minimized/normal windows) that use something other than the Win32 API?

Comment: *"It appears that Visual Studio doesn't support the creation of ActiveX controls"* - ActiveX is just COM (with a bit of metadata), and Visual Studio has full support for authoring COM objects. It's not entirely clear, why ActiveX being *"IE only"* is an issue for you, as you explicitly stated, that your application also is *"IE11 only"*.

Comment: Besides, the `Window`'s [outerWidth](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_outerheight.asp) and [outerHeight](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_outerheight.asp) properties appear to be exactly, what you're after. Why do you believe, that those do not work for you?